# How to put 2 ListView and put TextView in TableView after Listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, tablerow

I have 2 listview in 1 activity

Example:

```
[Tablerow - 4 Textview in 1 row]
[ListView1]
[Tablerow - 4 Textview in 1 row]
[ListView2]
```

I tried: **LinearLayout** and set to **Vertical**; **layout_weight**; **RelativeLayout**; **android:width**="0dp"; **layout_below / above**

Sometimes, the listview overlap, second tablerow not displayed.

May I know how to solve it ?

Here is my activity xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.bus">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/table1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvleaving"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/leaving"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hc1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/ch"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hc2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/westlake"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arriving"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/arrive"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="40dp" />


<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/table2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvleaving2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/leaving"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hc3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/ch"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hc4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/west"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arriving2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/arrive"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this way.

```
<LinearLayout  android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_weight="1">
  <TableRow/>
  <ListView/>
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout  android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_weight="1">
  <TableRow/>
  <ListView/>
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```